# How to convert word to number using my function?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, similarity

I created this function to converting numbers to words. And how I can convert words to number using this my function:

Simple function code:

```
$array = array("1"=>"ЯК","2"=>"ДУ","3"=>"СЕ","4"=>"ЧОР","5"=>"ПАНҶ","6"=>"ШАШ","7"=>"ҲАФТ","8"=>"ХАШТ","9"=>"НӮҲ","0"=>"НОЛ","10"=>"ДАҲ","20"=>"БИСТ","30"=>"СИ","40"=>"ЧИЛ","50"=>"ПАНҶОҲ","60"=>"ШАСТ","70"=>"ҲАФТОД","80"=>"ХАШТОД","90"=>"НАВАД","100"=>"САД");
  $n = "98"; // Input number to converting

if($n < 10 && $n > -1){ 
    echo $array[$n];
}
if($n == 10 OR $n == 20 OR $n == 30 OR $n == 40 OR $n == 50 OR $n == 60 OR $n == 70 OR $n == 80 OR $n == 90 OR $n == 100){
    echo $array[$n];
}

if(mb_strlen($n) == 2 && $n[1] != 0) 
{
    $d = $n[0]."0";
    echo "$array[$d]У ".$array[$n[1]];
}
```

My function so far converts the number to one hundred. How can I now convert text to a number using the answer of my function?

Comment: Can you provide the example of output?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the input specs but I took the assumption you want it with a space between the words.

```
   //get our input=>"522"
    $input = "ПАНҶ САД БИСТ ДУ";
    //split it up
    $split = explode(" ", $input);
    //start out output
    $c = 0;
    //set history
    $history = "";
    //loop the words
    foreach($split as &$s){
       $res = search($s);

       //If number is 9 or less, we are going to check if it's with a number
       //bigger than or equal to 100, if it is. We multiply them together
        //else, we just add them.
        if((($res = search($s)) <=9) ){
           //get the next number in the array
           $next = next($split);
           //if the number is >100. set $nextres
             if( ($nextres = search($next)) >= 100){
                //I.E. $c = 5 * 100 = 500
                $c = $nextres * $res;
                //set the history so we skip over it next run
                $history = $next;
             }else{
                 //Single digit on its own
                 $c += $res;
             }
        }elseif($s != $history){
            $c += $res;
        } 
    }
    //output the result
    echo $c;



    function search($s){
        global $array;

        if(!$res = array_search($s, $array)){
           //grab the string length
           $max = strlen($s);
           //remove one character at a time until we find a match
            for($i=0;$i<$max; $i++ ){
                 if($res = array_search(mb_substr($s, 0, -$i),$array)){
                    //stop the loop
                    $i = $max;
                   }
            }       
        } 

        return $res;
    }
```

Output is 522.

Comment: most likely there will be such answers: БИСТУ ДУ == 22, ПАНҶОҲУ ШАШ == 56, НАВАДУ НӮҲ == 99. So I marked the tag "similarity" for similar_text(). Or some other option. We still have a different postfix to words. It should be noted that only postfix can be added to the names of numbers.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that, I'm not educated in your language unfortunately. I'll take your note now and try to come up with a solution.

Comment: It is necessary to get rid of different postfixes. I also have my own option for solving this option. For example, you need to take the incoming word and check with all values in the array in a loop (for example, if you can generate a digit in the form of text only to 100 then the loop will be up to 99) and if there is no match, you need to simulate this string with the values of the array in the loop. And in the end you need to print the key found matching.

Comment: Is the only postfix `У` ?

Comment: So far, yes. That is, while my version is only up to a hundred and in this case only. And in another case I will create a continuation of the function and then publish a new question about this if there are problems.

Comment: In some figures, for example, in figure 2 ("ДУ"), too, there is at the end the letter "y" that's so normal. But we need to exclude such cases. By the way, there is still one postfix "woo" that can appear in the numbers 31 ("СИВУ ЯК"). It is better to create an array with postfixes so that in the future any new postfixes can be added. For example array $postfix = array("у","ву");

Comment: @John I've updated my code for the requirements and completed test cases. I've updated it to trim the letters by 1 or 2 depending if it found a match, therefore we don't need to have an array keeping count of our postfix

Comment: @John have you see this solution? It takes infinite inputs and solves all possible postfix addons.

Comment: Has problem when I input "НУЗДАҲ"

Comment: My array $array = array("1"=>"ЯК","2"=>"ДУ","3"=>"СЕ","4"=>"ЧОР","5"=>"ПАНҶ","6"=>"ШАШ","7"=>"ҲАФТ","8"=>"ХАШТ","9"=>"НӮҲ","0"=>"НОЛ",
      "ЁЗДАҲ"=>"11", "ДУВОЗДАҲ"=>"12","СЕНЗДАҲ"=>"13","ЧОРДАҲ"=>"14","ПОНЗДАҲ"=>"15","ШОНЗДАҲ"=>"16","ҲАБДАҲ"=>"17","ҲАЖДАҲ"=>"18","НУЗДАҲ"=>"19",
            "10"=>"ДАҲ","20"=>"БИСТ","30"=>"СИ","40"=>"ЧИЛ","50"=>"ПАНҶОҲ","60"=>"ШАСТ","70"=>"ҲАФТОД","80"=>"ХАШТОД","90"=>"НАВАД",
            "100"=>"САД", "1000"=>"ҲАЗОР", "1000000"=>"МИЛЛИОН");

Comment: @john please see that you have messed up your array. `"НУЗДАҲ"=>‌​"19"` is not in the format as the rest of the array, they must be like `​"19"=>"НУЗДАҲ"` then it will work

Comment: Sorry I it corrected but has another problem.  "ЯК САДУ НУЗДАҲ" must be 119 but your code returned 120.

Comment: FOR EXAMPLE "ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ЯК САДУ НУЗДАҲ" must be 1119 or "НУЗДАҲ ҲАЗОРУ ЯК САДУ БИСТУ НӮҲ" must be 19129 or "ЯК МИЛЛИОН НУЗДАҲ" must be 1000019

Comment: This is now getting to very tricky parts as I believe `ЯК МИЛЛИОН ДУ ҲАЗОР СЕ САД ПАНҶ` is something like `1002,305` but my program will return something such as `1001,108`. This is getting pretty complex now and I'm not fully sure how to solve it. This is because we are adding each element up together. This is very difficult to solve.

Comment: What we can to do? See please to incrementing letters:<pre>ЧОР - 4
ДАҲ - 10
БИСТ - 20
БИСТУ ЯК - 21
ПАНҶОВУ ШАШ - 56

САД - 100
ЯК САДУ ЯК - 101
ЯК САДУ БИСТУ ДУ - 122
ПАНҶ САДУ ПАНҶОВУ ҲАФТ - 557

ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ЯК САДУ ПАНҶОҲ - 1150
ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ШАШ САДУ СИВУ ҲАФТ - 1637
ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ҲАФТ САДУ ҲАФТОДУ ХАШТ - 1778

ЯК МИЛЛИОН НАВАД ҲАЗОРУ ПАНҶ САДУ ЧИЛУ НӮҲ - 1090549
ЯК МИЛЛИОН СЕ САДУ БИСТУ ДУ ҲАЗОРУ ҲАФТ САДУ ПАНҶОҲУ ШАШ - 1322756</pre>

Comment: I'll keep trying I'll poke you if I have anything

Comment: I tested but when in input "ПАНҶ САДУ БИСТ ДУ" in output I get 127

Comment: @John it seems PHP gives 127 for php 7.0+, I'll look into the reason for this now https://3v4l.org/SjI3o

Comment: What to do then so that in the new versions of php this code worked @WillParky93?

Comment: Well! Is your code to the point where it works more correctly? Have you checked this? In my testing this code works up to 1100. And is it possible? Although you can create not only one function. Is it possible for a number greater than 1100 to come up with another function?

Comment: The issue is now down to language constructs. I don't have the energy to keep working on this. As I said, it gets more and more complex. Numbers like "five hundred thousand" are a struggle. It will take "five million and two hundred". Please understand how complex this is.

Comment: Yes! Check this numbers please: 1101 == "ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ЯК САДУ ЯК",
1289 == "ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ДУ САДУ ХАШТОДУ НӮҲ",
1311 == "ЯК ҲАЗОРУ СЕ САДУ ЁЗДАҲ",
1525 == "ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ПАНҶ САДУ БИСТУ ПАНҶ",
1748 == "ЯК ҲАЗОРУ ҲАФТ САДУ ЧИЛУ ХАШТ",

Comment: Did you get something new in the code @WillParky93?

Answer (score 2):

So, as @WillParky93 assumed, your input has spaces between words.

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");//For testing purposes
$array = array("1"=>"ЯК","2"=>"ДУ","3"=>"СЕ","4"=>"ЧОР","5"=>"ПАНҶ","6"=>"ШАШ","7"=>"ҲАФТ","8"=>"ХАШТ","9"=>"НӮҲ","0"=>"НОЛ","10"=>"ДАҲ","20"=>"БИСТ","30"=>"СИ","40"=>"ЧИЛ","50"=>"ПАНҶОҲ","60"=>"ШАСТ","70"=>"ҲАФТОД","80"=>"ХАШТОД","90"=>"НАВАД","100"=>"САД");
$postfixes = array("3" => "ВУ");
$n = "98"; // Input number to converting
$res = "";
//I also optimized your conversion of numbers to words
if($n > 0 && ($n < 10 || $n%10 == 0))
{
    $res = $array[$n];
}  


if($n > 10 && $n < 100 && $n%10 != 0) 
{
    $d = intval(($n/10));
    $sd = $n%10;

    $ending = isset($postfixes[$d]) ? $postfixes[$d] : "У";
    $res = ($array[$d * 10]).$ending." ".$array[$sd];
}

echo $res;

echo "\n<br/>";
$splitted = explode(" ", $res);

//According to your example, you use only numerals that less than 100
//So, to simplify your task(btw, according to Google, the language is tajik
//and I don't know the rules of building numerals in this language)
if(sizeof($splitted) == 1) {
    echo array_search($splitted[0], $array);
}
else if(sizeof($splitted) == 2) {
    $first = $splitted[0];
    $first_length = mb_strlen($first);
    if(mb_substr($first, $first_length - 2) == "ВУ")
    {
        $first = mb_substr($first, 0, $first_length - 2);
    }
    else
    {
        $first = mb_substr($splitted[0], 0, $first_length - 1);
    }

    $second = $splitted[1];
    echo (array_search($first, $array) + array_search($second, $array));
}
```

Comment: Your code also works. But when I add the numbers "9" the answer is wrong when converting digits into text. That is your mistake in your condition. Check and compare your mistake please. Answer must be only "НӮҲ" but your code returned "НӮҲНОЛУ НӮҲ "

Comment: What will be your decision regarding the emerging postfixes? I marked this in the comments please read. I mentioned there about creating an array for an exception with the name $postfix = array("у", "ву");

Comment: @John could you tell me, when one must apply `у` and `ву`?

Comment: from 31 to 39 has postfix "ву",and on anoher situations "у".

Comment: @John thanks, I'll update my answer ASAP. Btw, could you tell me, how will be converted number, for example, 123?

Comment: 123  = ЯК САДУ БИСТУ СЕ. And I had some problem. For example, we have a digit from 11 to 19 for another to sound and not as usual, so I added them to the array with their keys, but when I create the condition, I have a problem. What can I do to solve this problem? New values in array("ЁЗДАҲ"=>"11", "ДУВОЗДАҲ"=>"12","СЕНЗДАҲ"=>"13","ЧОРДАҲ"=>"14","ПОНЗДАҲ"=>"15","ШОНЗДАҲ"=>"16","ҲАБДАҲ"=>"17","ҲАЖДАҲ"=>"18","НУЗДАҲ"=>"19", "1000"=>"ҲАЗОР", "1000000"=>"МИЛЛИОН")

Comment: @John sorry, but I will be able to update my answer only tomorrow. Need to sleep a lttle bit

Comment: Hello @Rulisp! Can you continue on yesterday's (this) question?